# Extract and print x,y coordinates from array of x,y where y between two predefined values

Tags: python, numpy

I searched for some points in an image using template matching

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread (map.png)
template=cv2.imread('temp.png',0)
```

I extracted x,y coordinates of these points now I have my data as array of values x,y. I need to print the points that have a y between 100 and 300 
I tried:

```
out= x[np.logical_and(y > 100, y < 300)]
print out
```

I need to show both coordinates not only the x.

Comment: So basically you have a numpy array. Aren't you just trying to slice the array then? Ex: `X[10:16, 5:11]`